# Arch Linux Install Scripts on MacBook Pro Retina

Tags: linux, installation, arch-linux, macbook-pro-retina

I've spent many hours trying to configure arch linux on my macbook pro. I get stuck at "Loading initial ram state" when I reboot after install.

Here is the script(s), I've created chronicling my steps. Is there anything obviously wrong that I am doing?

Thanks ahead of time.

```
cgdisk /dev/sda #(setup partitions as below, sda1-3 not shown)
#partitions: (sda4 == 128MB Hfs+, sda5 == 256MB Linux (boot), sda6 == 30GB Linux (root), sda7 == 70GB #Linux Home)
#first script

mkfs.ext2 /dev/sda5
mkfs.ext4 /dev/sda6
mkfs.ext4 /dev/sda7
mount /dev/sda6 /mnt
mkdir /mnt/boot && mount /dev/sda5 /mnt/boot
mkdir /mnt/home && mount /dev/sda7 /mnt/home
pacstrap /mnt base base-devel
genfstab -p /mnt >> /mnt/etc/fstab

arch-chroot /mnt /bin/bash

#second script
#install wifi (dmesg | grep firmware still says no firmware tho...)
pacman -S wget b43-fwcutter
wget https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/b4/b43-firmware/b43-firmware.tar.gz
tar -zxf b43-firmware.tar.gz
cd b43-firmware
makepkg -si --asroot #kosher?
rmmod b43 && modprobe b43
echo arch > /etc/hostname
ln -s /usr/share/zoneinfo/US/Central /etc/localtime
hwclock --systohc --utc
useradd -m -g users -G wheel -s /bin/bash dmj && passwd dmj
sudo pacman -S sudo
nano /etc/sudoers #comment out wheel portion
sudo nano /etc/locale.gen #pick locale
locale-gen
echo LANG=en_US.UTF-8 > /etc/locale.conf
export LANG=en_US.UTF-8
mkinitcpio -p linux #someone said i need "ahci" in modules?
#make boot loader, copy to usb
pacman -S grub-efi-x86_64
grub-mkconfig -o boot/grub/grub.cfg
grub-mkstandalone -o boot.efi -d usr/lib/grub/x86_64-efi -O x86_64-efi -C xz boot/grub/grub.cfg
mkdir /mnt/usbdisk && mount /dev/sdc1 /mnt/usbdisk
cp boot.efi /mnt/usbdisk/
umount /mnt/usbdisk/
sudo pacman -S dialog wpa_supplicant iw

exit
umount /mnt/home
umount /mnt/root
umount /mnt/
sudo reboot
```

Comment: http://lifehacker.com/5680453/build-a-killer-customized-arch-linux-installation-and-learn-all-about-linux-in-the-process seems to have a slightly different grub-install process (see Step 7). Might be worth comparing.

Comment: @James, yes but he doesn't seem to be installing Arch on a mac. http://codylittlewood.com/arch-linux-on-macbook-pro-installation/#comment-940585381

Comment: apologies, my bad - I'm assuming you've also looked at the Arch wiki? https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/MacBook

Comment: @James, Looking at my scripts above do you see anything out of the ordinary?

Comment: Maybe you forgot some modules in kernel, check my notes https://vec.io/posts/use-arch-linux-and-xmonad-on-macbook-pro-with-retina-display